# Serve file from Google Storage files via asp.net core webapi

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, google-cloud-storage

I have a website (webapi+c#+asp.net core) that serving files to the clients. The application expose the method to the `Download` file from the server.

The actual file is stored on Google Storage. So, the file is being downloaded to the server (stored in memory stream) and then returned to the caller.

This is my code:

```
[Route("download/{id}")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> DownloadAsync(string id)
{
    // Authentication...

    Uri remoteFile = item.GetEnpointResponse(); // Path to file in bucket
    using (StorageClient gcpStorage = await StorageClient.CreateAsync(remoteFile.GetCredentials().Credentials).ConfigureAwait(false))
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        await gcpStorage.DownloadObjectAsync("bucketName", "path/to/blob", ms, new DownloadObjectOptions
        {
            EncryptionKey = "XXX"
        }).ConfigureAwait(false);
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return File(ms, "application/json");
    }
}
```

Two problems I found:

1. It's storing all data of the file in the memory. If the file is large... its a hard job.
2. Waste of time - The file is being downloaded twice until getting to the client's hands.

Since this code is happening many times, I wonder if I can improve the performance of it? Something that I can improve here?

Comment: If the files are public, have the user download the file directly from Cloud Storage. If the files are private, generate a Presigned URLs and have the user download the file directly from Cloud Storage. When you are the middle man you are paying for the bandwidth. Review ingress and egress network bandwidth pricing for your design.

Comment: @JohnHanley I would suggest to post your comment as an answer, that is the correct approach what No1Lives4Ever is trying to accomplish

Comment: Did you get this figured out?  I am looking to just download a pdf file from Google Storage, can you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most elegant way I could find is the following, using the library [AspNetCore.Proxy](https://github.com/twitchax/AspNetCore.Proxy):

```cs
namespace Storage
{
    [Route("api/storage")]
    public class StorageController : Controller
    {
        private readonly string _bucketName;
        private readonly GoogleCredential _credential;
        private readonly UrlSigner _urlSigner;

        public StorageController(GoogleCredential credential, string bucketName)
        {
            _credential = credential;
            _bucketName = bucketName;
            _urlSigner = UrlSigner.FromServiceAccountCredential(_credential.UnderlyingCredential as ServiceAccountCredential);
        }

        [HttpGet("download/{file}")]
        public async Task DownloadFileAsync(string file)
        {
            using var storageClient = await StorageClient.CreateAsync(_credential);
            var signUrl = await _urlSigner.SignAsync(
                _bucketName,
                file,
                TimeSpan.FromHours(3),
                HttpMethod.Get
            );
            await this.HttpProxyAsync(signUrl);
        }
    }
}
```